# I am using Flyway database migration tool. Can I archive artifacts for what was migrated or they have to stay under current folder?

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I am using flyway database migration tool. Let's assume I have 100 sql scripts under a folder and I migrated them by applying on a server. Later I added 50 more sql scripts. Can I be able to move these 100 old sql scripts away and archive them somewhere (artifactory or remote share). That way I can only have 50 sql scripts which are new and needed for current migration.

Is this possible? Or all sql scripts has to be present under the directory?

Answer (score 2):

It would be useful if you could edit your question to state the reason why you want to only include the 50 scripts for the current migration, as this would help me recommend an approach.

There are two ways that I know of that you could use.

1. Create subfolders for each release, rather than have one single folder with an unmanageable list of scripts. This approach means that all migrations remain in the project, which has advantages such as being able to rebuild a test database from scratch (using flyway clean migrate) and also being able to reuse the project later on to repeat earlier deployments. If you do it this way, you will need to reference each subfolder using the [flyway.locations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/locations) parameter.
2. Remove the sql scripts that have already been run, as you have suggested. If you do this, you will need to run [flyway baseline](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/baseline) on any targets. This command will ensure that the targets don't expect migrations below a specific version, so the missing migration files won't confuse flyway.

My personal preference is the first option. If you can't use this for whatever reason, we'd be interested to understand why.

Comment: You could also use the [repair command](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair) to mark missing migrations as 'deleted'. That might be a bit misleading if you have actually just moved the scripts, but it still preserves the audit trail. The scripts can also be re-introduced later if you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much David Atkinson & Mikiel. Really appreciate your answers. That's the exact answers I was looking for. First option is the best and I will follow it (create subfolders for each release).

Comment: For option one, you should be able to use a wildcard in the flyway.location value to avoid needing to hard code all the subfolders.